# Null pointer when testing Robolectric Activity that starts with a progress dialog

Tags: android, dialog, robolectric

So I have an activity that starts out by making an HTTP request. I would like to show a progress dialog during the request, and that has been no problem. However adding the dialog broke my tests, and now I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:664)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.routeMessage(ShadowHandler.java:125)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.access$100(ShadowHandler.java:25)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler$1.run(ShadowHandler.java:110)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$PostedRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:162)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:107)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:92)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceToLastPostedRunnable(Scheduler.java:68)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:25)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:228)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:267)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:144)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:154)
at com.showmobile.android.showmobile.settings.BasicInfoActivityTest.setup(BasicInfoActivityTest.java:90)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
```

Here is some abridged code from the test:

```
private final ActivityController<BasicInfoActivity> controller = buildActivity(BasicInfoActivity.class);
private BasicInfoActivity activity;


@Before
public void setup() {
        activity = controller.create().start().resume().visible().get();
}
```

That activity = controller.create() line is where the error originates.
Below is the activity itself, trimmed down:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_info_activity);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    /** Some other irrelevant code goes here **/

    fetchCurrentUserProfile();
}

private void fetchCurrentUserProfile() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialogBuilder.buildProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.show();
    userService.loadCurrentUser().getAsynchronously(getUserProfileOperation());
}

private DeferredOperation<GetUserPrivateProfileApiResponse> getUserProfileOperation() {
    return new DeferredOperation<GetUserPrivateProfileApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(GetUserPrivateProfileApiResponse response) {
           /** Success handling code goes here **/
        }

        @Override
        public void complete(GetUserPrivateProfileApiResponse response) {
            if (profile == null) {
                profile = userService.getCurrentUser();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
}
```

The error goes away if I remove progressDialog.show();. I've tried to find examples of Robolectric tests where the activity starts by loading a dialog, but have had no luck so far. From stepping through the stack trace it looks like there could be some sort of issue with the Dialog not having an actual Context to work on, but I'm unsure. Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: It seems that showing the progressDialog in onResume() instead of onCreate() fixes the NPE, but in the actual Android environment it does not matter.

Comment: Same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @gleenn nope I never did. Still run into it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, ProgressDialog was also the issue, and as soon as I found a way to avoid .show() method being called, my test passed as well.